# animate a QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to animate a QGraphicsPixmapItem in PyQt5.
The program as is crashes without any error message, and removing the lines about the variable 'anime' makes the program work normally.

here is the QGraphicsPixMapItem:

```
class QStone(QGraphicsPixmapItem,QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, color, movable):
        QGraphicsPixmapItem.__init__(self)
        QGraphicsObject.__init__(self)

        if movable:
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

        white = QPixmap("ressources/white2.png")
        black = QPixmap("ressources/black_stone.png")
        empty = QPixmap("ressources/no_stone.jpg")


        if color == Player.white:
            self.setPixmap(white.scaled(60, 60, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        elif color == Player.black:
            self.setPixmap(black.scaled(60, 60, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        self.w = self.boundingRect().width()
        self.h = self.boundingRect().height()

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
        self.setOpacity(0.5)
        event.accept()

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.setOpacity(1.)
        event.accept()
```

the QGraphicsObject inheritance seems to be required for using QPropertyAnimation.

here is the code containing this animation:(this method belongs to a QGraphicsView's subclass):

```
def display_stone(self, x, y, color=None):
    stone = ""
    # if color is None:
    #     stone = QStone("", True)
    if color == Player.white:
        stone = QStone(Player.white, False)
    elif color == Player.black:
        stone = QStone(Player.black, False)

    stone.setOpacity(0.0)
    anime = QPropertyAnimation(stone, b"opacity",self)
    anime.setDuration(800)
    anime.setStartValue(0.0)
    anime.setEndValue(1.0)
    anime.start()

    stone.setPos(x - stone.w / 2, y - stone.h / 2)
    self.scene.addItem(stone)
    stone.setZValue(10)
```

any idea?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the Qt C++ API, PyQt does not allow double inheritance (except in exceptional cases<sup>(1)</sup>) so you cannot implement a class that inherits from QGraphicsPixmapItem and QGraphicsObject.

In this case there are the following options:

**1.** In this case it is to create a QObject that handles the property you want to modify, and that is the object that is handled by the QPropertyAnimation:

```py
class OpacityManager(QObject):
    opacityChanged = pyqtSignal(float)

    def __init__(self, initial_opacity, parent=None):
        super(OpacityManager, self).__init__(parent)
        self._opacity = initial_opacity

    @pyqtProperty(float, notify=opacityChanged)
    def opacity(self):
        return self._opacity

    @opacity.setter
    def opacity(self, v):
        if self._opacity != v:
            self._opacity = v
            self.opacityChanged.emit(self._opacity)


class QStone(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, color, movable=False):
        QGraphicsPixmapItem.__init__(self)

        self.manager = OpacityManager(self.opacity())
        self.manager.opacityChanged.connect(self.setOpacity)

        if movable:
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        # ...
```

```
# ...
anime = QPropertyAnimation(stone.manager, b"opacity", stone.manager)
# ...
```

**2.** Another option is QVariantAnimation:

```py
# ...
anime = QVariantAnimation(self)
anime.valueChanged.connect(stone.setOpacity)
anime.setDuration(800)
# ...
```

<sup>(1) https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qt_interfaces.html</sup>

Comment: it works, thank you. Yet I still get a problem, because the stones are displayed as the program continues to think about the next move, and it freezes the stones' display. I will try to animate them in separate threads.

Comment: @lolveley No, no, no ..... You cannot modify properties that are used for painting such as opacity from another thread since Qt prohibits it since it cannot guarantee its correct operation, and also in this case it does not help at all.

Comment: @lolveley Do not abuse threads, they are not magical entities that solve any problems since they have restrictions and if you implement them incorrectly they can do the opposite of what you expect. IMHO is the last option and I only use them when the task blocks the eventloop but in your case it is not. I think you have other problems.

Comment: @lolveley Do not edit your question, create a new post with your new question